# Navigation-based app + tab bar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I made a tab bar application with several tab bar buttons. Each button is linked to a separate xib file. This works for a xib with a UIViewController and a xib with a UITableViewController. However, it does not work for a xib with a UINavigationController.

On the left you can see what it looks like in Interface Builder, and on the right is what it looks like in the simulator.
[image]

Why isn't it showing up correctly in the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

But it looks like it's showing up correctly. You probably just need to add some code to your `UITableViewController` to populate the `tableView` and set a title for the navbar.